# How to Loop Over Date Range in ArangoDB

Tags: date, arangodb, echarts, arangojs

I need to return a value for every date between a start and end date.

For each `row`: if the date exists in `row.date`, then I need to return `row.myValue` else I need to return null.

Example:

```
dateRange = {start: '2018-01-01', end: '2018-01-03'}
aqlCollection = [
  {date: '2018-01-01', myVal: 1},
  {date: '2018-01-02', myVal: 2},
  {date: '2017-05-18', myVal: 3}
]
```

This should return:

```
[
  {'2018-01-01': 1},
  {'2018-01-02': 2},
  {'2018-01-03': null}
]
```

This can be accomplished simply if there was a `WHILE` loop in arangodb. Or if I could for loop using an incrementer instead of doing `FOR date IN dates` then I could just say `FOR date=startRange; date<endRange; date+=24hrs`.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved within an Arango query? If it is not possible I will do an O(n) loop over after a simple group by date query and add in all the dates that do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/functions/date/

If you have an attribute in the date format then you can enumerate the collection's items using a for-loop and use a filter on the attribute to get the dates in a certain range. As you already showed. Adding an index on the attribute will give you a nice speed up. It will make sure that only objects with matching dates will be inspected.

Comment: Yes but I need all dates within a certain range, not just the ones that exist in the collection. Doing a filter for dates will return only dates that exist in the data.

Comment: Sorry I was just called, when I started reading your question and did not read carefully enough. While I guess it would be better still to handle that in the client or in a different way you can try something like this: "FOR d IN 0..20 RETURN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_NOW()+d*3600*24*1000,'%yyyy-%mm-%dd')"

Comment: yeah probably best done outside the query, thank you for the help!